# How to test if a method is called when any unHandled exception occurs in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test for a angular component using karma-jasmine.

**profile.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss'],
    providers: [ProfileService, ProfileHandlerService]
})
export class ProfileComponent {

    constructor(private profileService: ProfileService, private profileHandlerService: ProfileHandlerService) {
           this.profileHandlerService.onUnhandledException$.subscribe(() => {
                this.profileService.closeAll();
            });
      }    
}
```

**profile-handler.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileHandlerService{
    private onUnhandledException = new Subject();
    public onUnhandledException$ = this.onUnhandledException.asObservable();

    constructor(private zone: NgZone, @Inject(ProcessError) private customErrorProcessor: customErrorProcessor) {    
        this.customErrorProcessor.onUnhandledException$.subscribe((error: string) => {
            this.onUnhandledException.next();
            this.closeApplication();
        });
    }
```

**profile.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('ProfileComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
                declarations: [ProfileComponent],
                providers: [ProfileService, ProfileHandlerService],
                schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
            }).compileComponents();
        }));
    
    beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
            profileService = TestBed.inject<ProfileService>(ProfileService);
            profileHandlerService= TestBed.inject<ProfileHandlerService>(ProfileHandlerService);
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
            tick();
        }));
    
    it('shall trigger closeAll', fakeAsync(() => {
            spyOn(profileService, 'closeAll');
            let eventTriggered = false;
            fixture.detectChanges();
            profileHandlerService.onUnhandledException$.subscribe(() => {
                eventTriggered = true;
            });
            tick();
            expect(dialogService.closeAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));
});
```

I am getting below error while trying to subscribe to profileHandlerService:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

**How can I test if the closeAll method has been called when any unHandled exception occurs...?**

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: make service in component public, you can try `useClass` and `useValue` and put spy on `(component.profileService,'closeAll')` . let me know if that works

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests in `profile.component.spec.ts` should test only `ProfileComponent`. `ProfileHandlerService` should be tested separately in its own spec file.

Otherwise component tests could fail because of bug in service, which of course is not good.

In unit tests you should provide known input and check if the output is as expected after processing by unit (in this case component).

Jasmine provides plenty of tools to cut relations between units. For a start I'd recommend you reading on jasmine spyOn.

E.g. following should let you cut the relation between `ProfileComponent` and `ProfileHandlerService`:
`spyOn(ProfileHandlerService, 'onUnhandledException$').and.returnValue(of(...));`

If you want to test behaviour between different components and services you should do it in e2e tests.

Comment: I don't want to test ProfileHandlerService. I just want to test whether closeAll() method is called if any unHandled exception occurs. I have tried spyOn(ProfileHandlerService, 'onUnhandledException$').and.returnValue(of(...)); but it shows me error: Argument of type '"onUnhandledException$"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'